# Why does my Java timer program not work on Mac?

Tags: java

Is there any reasons due to using java on Mac that my code below wouldn't work? It is working on Windows. However it will not display the GUI on a Mac, I have tried updating java and restarting the machine. It still doesn't display the GUI with the timer.Is it possible it could be the program (Eclipse) that i am using to code in?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerApplication extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private JTextField seconds;
    private JTextField minutes;
    private int nTimeDelay = 50;
    private int ticks = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerApplication frame = new TimerApplication();
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());;
        seconds = new JTextField();
        minutes = new JTextField();
        window.add(minutes);
        window.add(seconds);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(50, this);
        timer.start();
        ticks=0;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       if(event.getSource()==timer)
       {
           minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", (ticks*(nTimeDelay)/1000) / 60));
           seconds.setText(String.format("%02d",(ticks*(nTimeDelay)/1000) % 60));
           ticks++;
       }    
   }
}
```

Comment: It works on my OSX maschine.

Comment: So what happens when you execute it? No exception whatsoever? Does the process finish?

Comment: When i try to run the document it opens up a java window however no GUI appears and after waiting 20 minutes it still didn't display or close suggesting to me it is running in the background however wont display.

Comment: What is "a java window"?

Comment: I am writing the code using the Eclipse IDE, so when i run a program it opens Java as a separate application window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a multi-threading bug.

I think that there is inadequate synchronization between the "main" thread which initializes the `TimerApplication`  and assigns a value to `timer`, and the Swing event dispatcher thread (EDT) that will be executing the calls to tour `actionPerformed` method.  This means that *it is possible* for the `actionPerformed` call to never see the value that was assigned to `timer` in the other thread.

Net result: `event.getSource() == timer` would always be false.

One way to correct this would be make the following changes:

```
synchronized (this) {
    timer = new javax.swing.Timer(50, this);
    timer.start();
    ticks = 0;
}
```

and

```
synchronized (this) {
    if (event.getSource() == timer) {
        minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", ticks * nTimeDelay / 1000 / 60));
        seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", ticks * nTimeDelay / 1000 % 60));
        ticks++;
    }
}
```